# Is possible to use 2 Xbox 360 wireless controllers in PC, using just one receiver?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

Recently, I bought an Xbox 360 wireless controller for PC, which comes with the USB receiver...

I want to play ''Rayman Origins'' in co-op with my girlfriend, and I want to know if it is a good idea to buy a normal Xbox 360 wireless controller (for Xbox) and if it would work as a second player using the same USB receiver?

Or do I need to buy another Xbox 360 wireless controller for PC, and use the same receiver? Or use 2 receivers?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This [wireless receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2) product description on amazon specifies that you can use up to 4 wireless controllers with one single receiver.

To pair multiple controllers to the same receiver, simply follow [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933710) for each separate controller.

To summarize the instructions:

1. Plug in the gaming receiver to a USB port on your computer
2. Use the "Install Automatically" option if the Add New Hardware wizard pops up
3. Download the XBOX wireless controller software from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/xbox-360-wireless-controller-for-windows) and install
4. Once installed, turn on the controller by pressing the middle 'X' button
5. Press the connect button on the receiver (the light flashes green)
6. Press the connect button on the wireless controller (pictured below).

[image: connect controller]

Your Xbox wireless controller should now be connected to your machine.  Repeat steps 4-6 for each additional controller.

Comment: Upvoted, but I feel awful for making your rep `1244`.

Comment: @fredley gahhhh it was perfect.  hurry, downvote me 5 times.

Comment: thank you, cristal clear instructions, now at lunch time i will buy an normal xbox360 wireless controller (for xbox360 console), and i'll follow up your instructions! :D

Comment: And remember, if you also use it with an xbox-360 you'll have to associate it again with the console after using it for the pc... (first time it happened to me I forgot, and for a while I thought I'd broken my controller)

Comment: confirmed, it works using 2 controller with one receiver

Comment: Does having more than one receiver increase stability? I have 4 controllers connected to one pc and occasionally some of them get disconnected in the middle of the game. I am confident that this is not related to batteries.