# Connecting my Xbox 360 or One controller with my PC without paying for anything?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers, xbox-one

Can I connect my Xbox 360 or Xbox One controller to my PC using without purchasing anything?

Comment: No, that would be shoplifting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a wired controller will work without much additional effort. For any of these options, you will need to install the drivers before the controller can be used.

**Xbox 360 controller**

Drivers - [Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows)

- Wired: You can connect a wired controller to the PC via the USB cord and it will work.
- Wireless: You will need a [wireless receiver](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1PU0M52180&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Xbox+360+Accessories-_-9SIA1PU0M52180). After connecting the receiver, follow these steps:

  - Connect the wireless receiver to your PC.
  - Press the sync button on the wireless receiver.
  - Press the sync button on your Xbox 360 wireless controller.

**Xbox One Controller**

Drivers - [Download link](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/controller-pc-compatibility)

- Wired: You can use the included micro USB cord to connect your controller to the PC.
- Wireless: There is no support for connecting the controller wirelessly at this time.

Comment: Side note for Xbox 360 Wireless:  If you want an official Microsoft wireless adapter (the Newegg one is a clone), you have to buy it as a set with an Xbox 360 Controller.  Model number JR9-00011, UPC is (I think) 885370239423.

Comment: Note that a Xbox 360 wireless controller with the USB recharging cord will NOT work on a PC for playing games.  The cord is only for charging a wireless controller rechargeable battery.

Comment: Note that [you only need one wireless adapter for up to 4 controllers.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/81291/23597)